# couldn't host on EC2, django/nginx/gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy django web app on EC2, but I was not able to access the site at domain name and also I am not able to access the gunicorn. I tried the same on DigitalOcean and everything seemed fine and working well. I am trying to learn to deploy on EC2, but stuck.
I have tried many tutorials but unable to access. 
Thanks

Comment: If the answer below is not correct please provide a specific issue. Your currnet configurations and the like. Also try to `curl` or `wget` the local ip from the box itself.

Answer (score -1):

You have to allow inbound traffic for your instance.

> Security groups enable you to control traffic to your instance, including the kind of traffic that can reach your instance. For example, you can allow computers from only your home network to access your instance using SSH. If your instance is a web server, you can allow all IP addresses to access your instance via HTTP, so that external users can browse the content on your web server.
>
> To enable network access to your instance, you must allow inbound traffic to your instance. To open a port for inbound traffic, add a rule to a security group that you associated with your instance when you launched it.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html